# vba clear column to last used row?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using vba to try and clear a column from row 10 to the last used row.

The problem i have is some of my values have gaps in them like so:

```
1
2
3

5
6
7

8
9
```

Here is my code:

```
Sub Clear2()
ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

With Sheets(1)
    .Range("H10:H" & .Range("H10").End(xlDown).Row).ClearContents
    .Range("I10:I" & .Range("I10").End(xlDown).Row).ClearContents
    .Range("J10:J" & .Range("J10").End(xlDown).Row).ClearContents
    .Range("K10:K" & .Range("K10").End(xlDown).Row).ClearContents
    .Range("L10:L" & .Range("L10").End(xlDown).Row).ClearContents
    .Range("M10:M" & .Range("M10").End(xlDown).Row).ClearContents


End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = True
End Sub
```

The problem i am getting is my code only clears upto the first blank row, and then doesn't clear anything after like so:

```
5
6
7

8
9
```

Please can someone show me the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
With Sheets("mysheet") '<--| change "mysheet" to your actual sheet name
    Intersect(.Range(.Rows(10), .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count)), .Range("H:M")).ClearContents
End With
```

it uses

- `Range(range1, range2)` notation

  to return a `range` spanning from `range1` to `range2` ranges
- `Range("Col1:Col2")` notation

  to return a `range` spanning between from columns `Col1` to `Col2`
- `UsedRange` property of `Worksheet` object

  to return a rectangular range that embraces all actually "used" (i.e., not empty or formatted) cells

so:

- `.Range(.Rows(10), .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count))`

  gets all cells from row 10 to last "used" row
- `.Range("H:M")`

  gets all cells in column H to M
- intersecting the two above ranges you get the wanted range to clear contents of

Comment: @user7415328, did you get through it?

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, it needs an explanation to be an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Clear2()

    ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

    With Sheets(1)

        .Range("H10:H" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row).ClearContents
        .Range("I10:I" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row).ClearContents
        .Range("J10:J" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row).ClearContents
        .Range("K10:K" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row).ClearContents
        .Range("L10:L" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row).ClearContents
        .Range("M10:M" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row).ClearContents

    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = True

End Sub
```

Comment: this also clears the contents of my cells H9, I9, J9, K9, L9 and M9 :(

Comment: @user7415328 there must be other code which deletes the `Row 9` I have tested my code before and after I posted it can it deletes the rows from row 10 for columns H to M perfectly. But if you have a header row then Row 10 of the excel sheet will be the 9th row of data, in which case you will then need to change it from H10 to H11 for example.